# Vue: Array Input Bindings with Custom Components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Using Vue's `v-bind` syntax, we can bind a number of checkboxes with different value attributes to the same array, which will then contain the corresponding values of all checked checkboxes. See the example: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#checkbox

Is it possible to achieve the same with custom components? Let's say I define a component `CheckBox.vue` as follows:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const modelValue = ref(false);

const emit = defineEmits<{ "update:modelValue": [modelValue: boolean] }>();

function handle() {
  modelValue.value = !modelValue.value;

  emit("update:modelValue", modelValue.value);
}
</script>

<template>
  <label>
    <button type="button" @click="handle">
      <span v-if="modelValue">✔️</span>
    </button>
  </label>
</template>
```

Now I can use `v-model` to synchronize a variable with the value of my custom checkbox. How can I make it so that I can also use a number of these checkboxes and bind them to an array?

Simply using the component as it is defined in the question in combination with `v-bind` and an array does the following: The first checkbox will add a single item to the array, which will change between `true` and `false` when clicking the checkbox. The other boxes have no effect on the array. Setting the `value` attribute on the `button` does not change this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#__DEV__eNqVVEtu2zAQvQrDRa0ArlwgKFAo/jQJsmgXbdAU3URZyNLIZkKRBEk5NgydoZsue5CepxfoFTokJdtxDKNdSTPzZubNj2t6oVS8qIEmdGhyzZQlBmytxqlglZLakjXRUJKGlFpWpIfQ3sZ0NYf8cSqXrS0edAoXsXeeilTkUhhLMq3JyMWJ7u5PvX44CNkwDwoWKsUzC14iZJh3gRevK1kAH6UUQ6SULDJeA0ol08aiPECPf8EbQCLFfzjYOdM7+IItxmS99oU0DRkOnMJVscOc9qk1mKZks/jBSIEtXTvnlOayUoyD/qwsw36kNCHe4mwZ5/Lpo9dZXUO/03uGB/QPZul0Kb3RYEAvIKUbm830DLAtznx9+wmW+L8xYp01R/QR4xcwkteOY4Bd1qJA2js4z/aDnz4Ts6/memlBmK4oR9QhG49PKW7B1ZHSt3TP4jPvl4oGu7i7Rcf20rW1tlB0y+kTpnRn75SWyuDmFVAyATdOitZ+xAm5tRpL6BM//29Bd3ehdbbqk0spOWTivnHLGkJBxewm0jUKJrrr1arA2SfbEL12vYOPz4ROHdHIl441R6dtEzTWpEXgGW/DTGImcl4XYCZxFIw+1imZTF6AMaFruetPhKgutCMcHWDYJ77ImBn/bcNvAZiDhAj7lg2pPUoHkCXjFnTE8DzIaEz892Q0aoGtI/Y7juN93/4u6D4wSVwrXWcbP5GjDwheK8+mwP0vCtPaWimIXSl310HCw36fc5Y/YnZYgLBo6YZ14n9S2vpjBKMygQ8FKzsUGn///PHn13ckgbYXSOAGxq/E1KjzZ4jhIKQPLAcdzWevyNDYFQeCD4mCAuXg4Wf6xAo7T8jbN2rpZz4HNptbvJ5OUeFBMZG8a8W81kbqhCjJBE4Du+fb5uKPafMXqeMMqA==)

You have to use `value` property as for `<input type="checkbox">`:

App.vue

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Checkbox from './Checkbox.vue';

const arr = ref([]);

</script>

<template>

  <checkbox v-model="arr" name="first" />
  <checkbox v-model="arr" name="second" />
  <checkbox v-model="arr" name="third" />
  <div> {{ arr }} </div>
</template>
```

Checkbox.vue

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({name: String, modelValue: [Array, Boolean]});
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);

const value = computed({
  get(){
    return props.modelValue?.includes?.(props.name) ?? props.modelValue;
  }, set(val){
    emit('update:modelValue', Array.isArray(props.modelValue) ? 
    props.modelValue.includes(props.name) ?  props.modelValue.filter(item => item !== props.name) : [...props.modelValue, props.name]
    : val);
}});


</script>

<template>
  <label>
    <button type="button" @click.prevent="value = !value">
      <span v-if="value">✔️</span>
      <span v-else>&nbsp;</span>
    </button>
  </label>
</template>
```

You can though keep `Checkbox.vue` as simple as handling a boolean value only. For that you use `computed` to get the same array from an object properties bound to the checkboxes:

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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)

App.vue

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Checkbox from './Checkbox.vue';

const arr = ref([]);

</script>

<template>

  <checkbox v-model="arr" value="first" />
  <checkbox v-model="arr" value="second" />
  <checkbox v-model="arr" value="third" />
  <div> {{ arr }} </div>
</template>
```

`Checkbox.vue` could be left the same (handling both arrays and booleans) but could be simplified in this scenario:

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({value: String, modelValue: [Array, Boolean]});
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);

const value = computed({
  get(){
    return props.modelValue?.includes?.(props.value) ?? props.modelValue;
  }, set(val){
    emit('update:modelValue', Array.isArray(props.modelValue) ? 
    props.modelValue.includes(props.value) ?  props.modelValue.filter(item => item !== props.value) : [...props.modelValue, props.value]
    : val);
}});


</script>

<template>
  <label>
    <button type="button" @click.prevent="value = !value">
      <span v-if="value">✔️</span>
      <span v-else>&nbsp;</span>
    </button>
  </label>
</template>
```

Comment: That means that there is no built-in way to do this for custom components, and instead I'd have to recreate the functionality like you did?

Comment: @Piet, yes, have to, not so complex though, you can make a generic composable to handle Array/Boolean models like in the Checkbox.vue. If this answers your question, please accept my answer (the checkbox)